# Delete a row from a .cvs file?

Tags: java, file, io

I have a large file that I need to delete a particular row from. I have the exact row number I want to be deleted and I cannot find a solution to a way to go directly to this line and delete it.

Most answers in StackOverflow simply suggest to iterate through the entire file and basically copy it over to a temp file and when the targeted line is found, simply not include it, swap filenames and delete.

This is does not seem like a very efficient solution especially for a large file and it ticks me to have to use it. Any other ideas that don't take this approach?

Comment: Please share and __post the links__ to `Most answers`. I doubt there is any _more direct_ alternative to the __buffered approach__ (reading entire file into a buffer, cut out the line and write the buffer to file again).

Answer (score 0):

What the other stackoverflow files are suggesting is not only efficient solution. It is a very effecient solution.

The best you can do is to allocate a large buffer as large as your memmory allows it. Read everything before the line everything after the line. Combine in a new file.

When a file is created it does not just create the file name. The operating system also allocates the space the file is taking, if we presume we do as you say. Remove a line from a file effectivly this would mean to shrink the allocated space. How do you think this is achieved ? By allocating a new chunk of memory.